# how to save the sorted arrays in textfile?

Tags: c++

I have a program that sorted arrays how can i save in text file?
for example: the sorted arrays is: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.
how can i save in text file named. Sorted elements".
I've tried many ways but the sorted array wouldn't save in text file.
I am a newbie so I find it difficult.

here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Enter number of element:";
    int n; cin >> n;
    int a[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cout << "element number " << (i+1) << " : ";
        cin >> a[i];
    }
    int e=1, d=3;
    int i, j, k, m, digit, row, col;
    int length = sizeof(a)/sizeof(int);
    int bmat[length][10];
    int c[10];
    for(m=1;m<=d;m++)
    {
        for(i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            c[i]=-1;
        }
        for(i=0;i<length;i++)
        {
            digit=(a[i]/e)%10;
            c[digit]++;
            row=c[digit];
            col=digit;
            bmat[row][col]=a[i];
        }
        k=-1;
        for(i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            if(c[i]!=-1)
            {
                for(j=0;j<=c[i];j++)
                {
                k++;
                a[k]=bmat[j][i]; 
                }
            }
        }
        e=e*10;
    }

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Sorted array:" << endl;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cout << a[i] << " , ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Serialization is one way.

Comment: open a file and write to it. You can use the sort function from <algorithm> to sort.

Comment: `int a[n];` when `n` is not a constant expression is *not* standard C++. Instead you should probably be using `std::vector`.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, which compiler does allow  int a[n]? VS6.0 or a Borland C++ Builder?

Comment: @ValentinHeinitz Most recent compilers allow it for the sake of compatibility with C99. The C++ committee has been scratching their heads for years over how to cleanly add that feature to C++. With older compilers the only alternative is `alloca`.

Comment: @Potatoswatter Good to know, thank you very much! I'm not up to date :-(

Answer (score 2):

```
//Use this code 

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;



int main()
{

    int n = 0; 
    cout << "Enter number of element:";
    cin >> n;

    //Data Structure
    std::vector<int> list;
    //push back element in vector
    for(register int i=0;i<n;++i)
        list.push_back(rand()%10 + 1);

    //do shuffling before sorting because rand() generates increasing order number
    std::random_shuffle(list.begin(),list.end());

    std::sort(list.begin(),list.end());

    ofstream textfile;
    textfile.open ("E:\\example.txt");
    for(size_t i= 0;i<list.size();++i)
        textfile << list[i] <<" ";

    textfile.close();
}
```

Comment: It's traditional to `srand` before `rand`, but `rand`'s [days](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3775.pdf) are [numbered](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3841.pdf).

Comment: Thank you @Potatoswatter It's helpful document.

Answer (score 1):

If you can write the sorted array to `std::cout`, then you can write it to a file. In C++, the console is the same as a file.

Put this at the end of `main`:

```
 cout << "Sorted array:" << endl;
 print_array( std::cout, a, n ); // Show the results to the user.

 std::ofstream save( "array.txt" ); // Open a new file (or overwrite).
 print_array( save, a, n ); // Save the results for later.

 system("pause");
 return 0;
}
```

and put the printing code in a new function, which may be defined before `main`:

```
void print_array( std::ostream & s, int * a, int n ) {
 for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
 {
  s << a[i] << " , ";
 }
 s << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

int compare(int, int);
void sort(int[], const int);
int compare(int x, int y){
    return(x > y);
}
void swap(int *x, int *y){
    int temp;
    temp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = temp;
}
void display(int array[], int n){
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++) {
        cout << array[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
void writeToFile(int array[], int n){
    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open("example.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++) {
        myfile << array[i];
        if (i != n - 1){
            myfile << ", ";
        }
    }
    myfile.close();
}
void sort(int table[], const int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < n - 1; j++) {
            if (compare(table[j], table[j + 1]))
                swap(&table[j], &table[j + 1]);
        }
    }
}
int main(){
    int quantity;
    int* tab;
    ofstream outfile;
    cout << "Enter number of element: ";
    cin >> quantity;
    tab = new int[quantity];
    cout << "Element:\n\n" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < quantity; i++){
        int x = i;
        cout << "#" << ++x << ":";
        cin >> tab[i];
    }
    sort(tab, quantity);
    cout << "The Sorted Elements are: ";

    display(tab, quantity);
    writeToFile(tab, quantity);
    cout << endl;
    getchar();
    getchar();
    //system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

in short, add this block to your code:

```
ofstream myfile;
myfile.open("example.txt");
for (int i = 0; i<n; i++) {
    myfile << array[i];
    if (i != n - 1){
        myfile << ", ";
    }
}
myfile.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use C++ fstream class, since you want to output, you can use ofstream here. You should just replace some "cout" with ofstream instance:

At the beginning of the code state it:

```
ofstream ofs("./sorted_elem.txt", ofstream::out);
```

When want to output:

```
    ofs << "Sorted array:" << endl;

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        ofs << a[i] << " , ";
    }
    ofs << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

In C++ you really want to use `std::vector` or some other nice container for storing arrays of numbers.  For writing an array to file you need to open the file and individually write each element to the file (all untested).

```
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
  std::ofstream fp("output.txt");
  int data[5]; // todo: fill

  for (unsitned i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
  {
    fp << data[i] << ' ';
  }
}
```

And to read again:

```
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
  std::ifstream fp("output.txt");

  // todo: Determine the size of the array or guess it (don't guess it!)
  unsigned array_size = 5;
  int data[array_size];

  int n = 0;
  while (fp.good() && n < array_size) fp >> data[n++];
}
```

But because we are using C++, we can use `std::vector`:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> me(5); // todo: fill

  std::ofstream fp("output.txt");

  for (size_t i = 0; i < me.size(); ++i) fp << me[i] << ' ';

  // C++11: for (int d : me) fp << d << ' ';
}
```

And,

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  std::ifstream fp("output.txt");

  std::vector<int> data;
  double buf;
  while (fp >> buf) data.push_back(buf);  // no longer need to guess
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, the copy option was not demonstrated here so far.

Please check this code. (Assuming your vector is ready to use, I've skipped it).

The example uses a C-array and a vector. Please use the later in your code whenever possible. But however, for copy-function both work:

```
#include <iostream>     
#include <iterator>    
#include <vector>      
#include <algorithm>    
#include <fstream>     

int main () {

  int a[10]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};  
  std::vector<int> v; for (int i=0; i<10; ++i)v.push_back(i*10); //0, 10, 20,...

  std::ofstream fs_a( "c:/temp/out_a.txt" );
  //store space separated
  std::copy ( a, a+sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]), std::ostream_iterator<int>( fs_a, " ") );

  //store coma-separated, as one-liner  
  std::copy ( v.begin(), v.end() ), std::ostream_iterator<int>( std::ofstream( "c:/temp/out_v.txt" ), ",") );
  return 0;
}
```